# Can I change or remove Touchwiz in Galaxy S4 running Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-touchwiz

I just upgraded my Galaxy S4 to Lollipop. It is not to my liking. I'm considering options to buy a non Android phone just so I don't have to look at it.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: What is it you don't like? Is it the icons, the new ui, any new functions. If it is everything i will post instructions on how to install a previous version of android.

Comment: The colors are terrible, the animations are terrible, the icons are terrible.. in short, everything. I like the way this looks: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Android_5.0-en.png So maybe a tutorial on removing TouchWiz?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the launcher that you don't like the look of, install a launcher from Google Play.

Or if the whole UI is not what you like then install a custom android rom, like [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/)

Answer (score 0):

TouchWiz Launcher can be replaced with any other launcher to your liking from `Google Play Store`. If you plan on removing TouchWiz altogether, I suggest flashing a custom ROM specific to your device.
See this article [here](http://theunlockr.com/2014/04/29/install-custom-rom-samsung-galaxy-s4/) for details on flashing your phone.

Comment: Is it possible to install just plain, default Android?